# Split rule of args in main function in Java?

Tags: java, args

Here is a strange problem I ran into:

I create a single program to print all the received args, Here is the code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i ++) {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I built a jar file of it and ran the following command:

```
java -jar test.jar test&1
```

However, it didn't print "test&1" as expected. The result of it is:

```
test
'1'is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

So my question is: what is the seperation of args? If I really need to receive "test&1", what should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing to do with Java. The `&` character is special to the Windows shell *(I can tell it's Windows from the error message)*: It separates two commands on one line, so what you're doing is telling the shell to run `java -jar test.jar test` and then run `1`. If you want to pass `test&1` to Java, you'll have to put it in quotes:

```
java -jar test.jar "test&1"
```

The `&` is also special on *nix shells (but in a different way, it runs the command in a sub-shell). There, you could use quotes as above, or put an `\` before the `&` instead. But not on Windows.